# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue in latest Flutter version

Tags: ios, flutter

I am launching my flutter app just after updating Flutter to the last version and now there are errors. Prior to the update the app launched fine.

Here you have the debug console output:

```
Xcode build done.                                            6.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/modestovascofornas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.5/ios/Classes/FWFWebViewHostApi.h:4:8

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/modestovascofornas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.5/ios/Classes/FWFWebsiteDataStoreHostApi.h:4:8

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/modestovascofornas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.5/ios/Classes/FWFUserContentControllerHostApi.h:4:8

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/modestovascofornas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.5/ios/Classes/FWFWebViewConfigurationHostApi.h:4:8

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/modestovascofornas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.5/ios/Classes/FWFUIDelegateHostApi.h:4:8

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/modestovascofornas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.5/ios/Classes/FWFScrollViewHostApi.h:4:8

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/modestovascofornas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.5/ios/Classes/FWFUIViewHostApi.h:4:8

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @HamzaMalik, I made a backup of the project iOS folder, then removed the iOS folder and then created it again, and that solved the issue

Comment: I tried this but it is giving me same error